How to set DTO props as optional, but never allow all of them null?
I'm trying to apply a validation using class-validator to make possible that some props can be @IsOptional, but if all of them is null, throw an exception.
Thinking in some approach like this:
@IsNotEmpty() //<------------- something like this
export class UpdateUsersDTO {
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  @ApiProperty()
  name: string;

  @IsEmail()
  @EmailIsUniq({ message: 'This email is already being used' })
  @IsOptional()
  @ApiProperty()
  email: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsStrongPassword({
    minLength: 8,
    minLowercase: 1,
    minNumbers: 1,
    minSymbols: 1,
    minUppercase: 1,
  })
  @IsOptional()
  @ApiProperty()
  password: string;
}

Is there any class validator? Or some approach to make it happens using the validators on each prop?
I tried using groups validator but got no success.
@IsNotEmpty({
    groups: ['update'],
  })


From my experience, I don't think that class-validator provides a decorator for the use case you mentioned here. For me you have to create a custom decorator where you will implement this logic of verification of all null or undefined value and then assigned this decorator to your DTO class.
I'm not really perfectly aware of the custom decorator development but for me it would be something like that.
function IsNotAllNullOrUndefined(
  propertyNames: string[],
  validationOptions?: ValidationOptions
) {
  return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      name: 'isNotAllNullOrUndefined',
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName: propertyName,
      options: validationOptions,
      validator: {
        validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
          const relatedValues = propertyNames.map((prop) => args.object[prop]);
          return relatedValues.some((val) => val !== null && val !== undefined);
        },
        defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {
          return `${propertyNames.join(', ')} cannot all be null or undefined at the same time.`;
        },
      },
    });
  };
}

The package class-validator provide to you some utility functions and types that will allow you to register a new custom decorator with a specific verification logic, like the verification of all null or undefined value here in your case, and then applied this new decorator to your DTO class as follow :
@IsNotAllNullOrUndefined(['name', 'email', 'password'], {
  message: 'At least one of name, email, or password must be provided.',
})
export class UpdateUsersDTO {
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  @ApiProperty()
  name: string;

  @IsEmail()
  @IsOptional()
  @ApiProperty()
  email: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  @ApiProperty()
  password: string;
}


Thanks for the answer. Your suggestion make sense, but I was not able to trigger the validate function when I used the DTO on a request. I tried a variation of your suggested code and also some differents options, but got no success.

What are the behaviors you encountered with the different options you have tried ?

sim just able to get the object of the class itself, no the instance of the DTO. also, I’m not able to trigger the validate function when the request using the DTO is done. I tried some options and almost all I have exactly the same behavior.
